# What does "expensive dinosaur" means?

Tags: idioms

I'm studying english watching a netflix drama "Emily in Paris".

I don't understand that mean of "**expensive dinosaur**" in a conversation.

---

Emily is working for Savoir as marketing company.

Olivia Thompon in Duree's CMO. (Duree is a cosmetic company)

Duree was used to be a client of Savior.

---

Olivia wanted to hire Emily as an influencer to promote Duree products.

Emily declined an offer and suggested that work with Savoir to Olivia.

Olivia said "I fired your agency. They're a very **expensive dinosaur**"

---

Is it an idiom?
Could you let me know how to understand it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not a set phrase, just a figurative use of the word "dinosaur". Calling someone or something a dinosaur means that their style or methods are old and out-of-date, and do not have a place in a modern setting. Calling an advertising agency a dinosaur means they have not adapted to the 21st century, possibly preferring things like print advertising campaigns to social media approaches, or using sexist tropes that would be more befitting of the 1950s than 2020s. Calling them an *expensive* dinosaur means that they charge a lot of money for their outdated methods.

Olivia is saying that she fired the advertising agency because they charge a lot of money, and do not produce work that is appropriate for a modern setting.

Comment: Oh, I understood perfectly!!
Really thank you for your detailed explanation :)

Comment: This figurative use of dinosaur to mean something out of date can be found in the dictionary ([_Cam_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dinosaur))